# Is this picture of Oshino Ougi light novel art or fanart?

Tags: monogatari-series

Is this picture of Oshino Ougi art from the light novels or fanart?

If it is light novel art, which light novel of the monogatari series is it from?

If it is a fanart, does it have anything to do with the light novels (meaning does this scene takes place in the light novels)?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is an edited version of official art that appeared in the first volume of *Owarimonogatari*. Full cover taken from [Amazon Japan](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E7%B5%82%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E-%E4%B8%8A-%E8%AC%9B%E8%AB%87%E7%A4%BEBOX-%E8%A5%BF%E5%B0%BE-%E7%B6%AD%E6%96%B0/dp/4062838575/) below:

[image: Owarimonogatari vol. 1 cover]

The first volume [appears](http://bakemonogatari.wikia.com/wiki/Owarimonogatari#Book_One) to contain "Ougi Formula", "Sodachi Riddle", and "Sodachi Lost". I haven't read the light novels, but the anime adaptation contains no scene that *exactly* corresponds to this.

Ougi never appears in a strapless black dress among classroom furniture: her interactions with Araragi take place after school, and thus, she wears the Naoetsu Private High School uniform. However, in the present-day portion of "Ougi Formula", she is locked in an empty classroom with Araragi. (She seems to only appear outside of school in the other stories.) This cover art could perhaps have been created with that setting in mind.

Comment: Spot on. The art in the light novel is usually of scenes that don't happen in the story.